# login for multiple users

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm trying to make a login for multiple users (for example: for stores. Every store has id and password).

That means that I want to use **one mySQL database for all stores**.

Each of the stores (after log in) will see a different content drawn from the database.

I currently have a log in that works for one store (just pulling the content from the database). What do I need to modify so that each store can take the relevant data from the database?

I know I can make a diffrent schema for each store, but there must be an easier way.

Comment: use a unique id for each store and use as foriegn key in every table. now you can fetch data of that store by using that id (maintained in session)

Comment: you just give privilage to all users

Comment: Anand Somasekhar: that means i have to use a foriegn key in every table, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when user logged in successfully, you have to generate **session**

`$_SESSION['user_id'] = $userid`

for and save user id as unique value and whenever you require to fetch data from db for specific user, use this session value    in your query. That's why you need to use `user_id` as foreign key in table.